# Understanding comparing optional strings

Tags: swift

I'm using the following code:

```
let optionalString:String? = ""
print(optionalString == nil)
```

The optional `String` contains a null value. When comparing it, however, it prints `false`. I don't understand why this is the case when running the program. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: You might want to ask yourself why a valid string (albeit an empty one) would be ever equivalent to nil. Is there a reason you'd expect this?

Answer (score 5):

This `""` is not a `nil` value

```
let optionalString:String?=""
```

it would be if you declared it like this

```
var optionalString:String?
```

Comment: why we cannnot use let?

Comment: If you use `let`, then you will not be able to change the values of `optionalString`

Comment: because immutable  nil string  is meaningless to compiler

Comment: If you use `let`, the Swift compiler will not assign `nil` to the optional, because then you'd never be able to change it to anything else.  With a `var` the compiler will go ahead and give it a `nil` value knowing that it can always be changed later.  If you really want `nil`, then assign it yourself `let optionalString: String? = nil`.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Maybe I'm misreading your answer but are you trying to say that the two lines of code in your answer are equivalent? They are not the same at all.

Comment: @rmaddy  No , I don't say that , the op thought that assigning `""` to a variable makes it `nil` so i added the last line of code in answer as the 1 he should think of

Answer (score 4):

An **optional** in Swift is a type that can hold either a **wrapped value** or **nil**

```
var name:String? 
var name:String? = nil
```

name is of type optional and may have String value or a nil value 
 
name now is nill

```
name = ""
```

name is an optional string has this "" value

NOTE : "" is a value is an empty string not nil but "" != " " != "  " ,etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to instantiate your string as null, then you should declare it as so

`var optionalString: String? = nil`

Creating it as a let would be literally meaningless as you would be instantiating a `nil` value that can never be changed.

Comment: You wouldn't need to explicitly set it to `nil`.

Comment: True, just added it there for better context.